# Is it possible to map a property based on a criteria in EF Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have an Employee entity that has multiple Unit entities they are associated too in various ways (e.g. as a Manager, Supervisor, etc...).  What their relationships are to a Unit are defined in a UnitRelationships table that includes an IsActive attribute in addition to EmployeeId, UnitId, and RelationshipTypeId attributes.

What I'd like to do is create specific properties on the Employee entity as such:

```
SupervisedUnits {get;set;}
ManagedUnits{get;set;}
```

... and configure the mapping so that "SupervisedUnits" returns only the Units where an active (IsActive = true) relationship exists and the RelationshipTypeId='Supervisor'.  Same type of thing with ManagedUnits.

So, is there a way to do this in EF Code First so that I can actually use these properties (SupervisedUnits and ManagedUnits) in my LINQ-to-Entities queries?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to introduce inheritance to your model. You say it's Code First but your question is phrased as if it is database first. Have you reverse engineered the database?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a couple of ways of doing this.

1. The "Active" relationship is a one to many between Unit and Employee and the "Inactive" relationship is many-to-many. So set them up as two different relationships and when the relationship is made inactive, move the `Supervisor` into the `InactiveSupervisors`. Doing it this way gives you a `SupervisedUnits` navigation property (as you wanted) and an `InActiveSupervisedUnits` property
2. The relationship is many-to-many and has attributes such as `IsActive`, `ActiveFrom` and `ActiveTo`. Now the relationship really needs to be an entity. You could use inheritance on your UnitRelationship entity:

   ```
   public class SupervisorUnitRelationShip : UnitRelationship{ }
   ```

   `public class ManagerUnitRelationShip : UnitRelationship
       {
       }`

then you can add your navigation properties by type:

```
public virtual Collection<SupervisorUnitRelationship> SupervisedRelations {get;set;}
public virtual Collection<ManagerUnitRelationship> ManagedRelations {get;set;}
```

to get to the Units you'll have to go through the UnitRelationship

`var SupervisedUnits = SupervisedRelations.Units;`